# improving the count() performance in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, count, innodb

I have a mysql query like below.

```
   SELECT `indexVal`, COUNT(`indexVal`) 
   FROM `key_word` 
   WHERE `hashed_word` IN ('001','01v','0ji','0k9','0vc','0@v','0%d','13#' ,'148' ,
                           '1e1','1sx','1v$','1@c','1?b','1?k','226','2kl','2ue',
                           '2*l','2?4','36h','3au','3us','4d~') 
   GROUP BY `indexVal`
```

This query take 5 seconds to generate the results! I even have a compound index created with `ALTER TABLE key_word ADD INDEX (hashed_word, indexVal)`. Please note that my query is counting how many times `indexVal` appeared in the "search" and not how many times it appears in the "table".

My table is having 3 columns, 28 million records, future table will have billions of records. I am using InndoDB, I just selected it. Below is my table `Show Create Table` result

```
CREATE TABLE `key_word` (
 `primary_key` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `indexVal` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hashed_word` char(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`),
 KEY `hashed_word` (`hashed_word`,`indexVal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28570982 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I ran the above `select` query with `Explain` command. Below is the result

[image]

So how can I speed up this? I prefer to have the result in less than 1 second. I appreciate your advice.

PS: I don't need the result to be in any order.

Comment: in your previous question you had where `hashed_word IN` however in this question appears be on `WHERE indexVal` . Now for index you have comnibed index and it will always look for left most prefix and you have `KEY hashed_word (hashed_word,indexVal)` so its not taking index

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: Thank you for noticing it. I updated the question with the correct query.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: can `MyIsam` storage help me?

Comment: well you have a lot of records so looking how it could be solved.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: Thanks. Can a paid system like MS SQL Server can help me?

Comment: JUst try to add the `hashed_word` to index. Looks like the problem is the table's fullscan to check all records for the values used in the **IN**

Comment: @StanislavL: Thanks. iT Is already in "compound index". Now what should I do? Can create the new index on top of it or something?

Comment: sorry my laptop battery went down. well your query is taking the indexes but not sure if something else is making it slow, it could be network speed, hardware etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try an index with reversed orders of columns:

```
create index xx on key_word( `indexVal`,`hashed_word`);
```

This may help prevent from using the filesort by the optimizer, 
but I don't think that this can help to speed up the query by 500% from 5 sec to less than 1 sec.
You probably need a faster hardware.

Comment: so, I need to drop the current index?

Comment: Hardware? My RAM is 4GB, what amount of RAM do you recomment? Can MS SQL Server help me?

Comment: 4GB?  You should probably be running _at least_ 16GB.  And appropriate OS  versions, disk types, etc.  If your production db is going to have billions of rows, it's going to choke badly on that kind of limited hardware.  For further questions of that type, go ask [our DBAs](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).  5 seconds sounds ~decent for several million rows, even with an index.  SQL Server _might_ help with this, but I'm not as versed with relative merits in that direction.  SQL Server _does_ have some **very** nice features that MySQL doesn't have, that make some queries very easy to write...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: OK, so you believe MSSQL Server will be faster?

Comment: ... your choice of server is unlikely to be the limiting factor in the current problem you're experiencing...

Comment: @Dongle Yes. Drop the current index, and recreate it in reverse order

Comment: A materialized view probably can help in this case, but MySql doesn't support materialized views, like Oracle, PostgeSQL and SQL Server (in SQL Server they are called `indexed views`). MySql isn't the best choice for this application.